# Does Google Analytics only track domain names?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics (GA) account for an existing site. We're developing a new site on a different live server, and I believe GA is tied to the domain name, not the IP address of the website. With the GA code installed on the development site before launch, once the DNS switch is made, GA should track the new site automatically, correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the tag will work as you suggest.

But, if you originally set up the tag to track multiple versions of the same domain and/or multiple sub-domains, then adding the tag to the dev site may mess up your existing analytics as it will still record data.

You could park the development site on a sub-domain and [track it seperately](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/5xjSOvb6AMQ) if the data is useful to you, otherwise don't add in the tag until you are in the process of going live.